# Inherit the existing view(view_partner_form) in my custom module

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-9

I have to inherit the view_partner_form from res.partner model in base module and I need to add some extra fields at contact form(view_partner_form) in my custom module but I tried this the impact is my extra fields are added correctly but UI totally collapse

This is my python code:

```
class Residents(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _name = "residents.details"

    f_no = fields.Char()
    id_proof = fields.Selection([('aadhar_card','Aadhar Card')],string = "Id Proof")
    id_no = fields.Char(string = "Id no")
```

**xml code:**

```
 <record id = "add_field_view_partner_form" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name">add.fields</field>
        <field name = "model">residents.details</field>
        <field name = "inherit_id" ref = "base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <field name = "city" position="before">
               <field name = "f_no" placeholder = "Flat No"/>
            </field>
            <field name = "lang" position="after">
               <field name = "id_proof" />
            </field>
            <field name = "id_proof" position="after">
                <field name = "id_no" />
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**Update**

Pls Find the ScreenShot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Collapse means? Can you please add pic of it?

Comment: Hi Viki, Please find the screenshot in the update section.

Comment: I am still not getting your point. I think screen is okay.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the screen shot is a form that odoo generate and it contains
all field in two columns layout. and odoo do that when your model don't have
any form view at all. smart odoo ^^.

Here you are in the same case when you inherit the view you changed the model name!!

```xml
    <record id = "add_field_view_partner_form" model = "ir.ui.view">
            <field name = "name">add.fields</field>
            <!-- you should keep the same name res.partners -->
            <!-- in this code you removed the model name and most 
            lickly this is why you lost the the view and this is why
            odoo is showing you the generated form view -->
            <field name = "model">residents.details</field>
            <field name = "inherit_id" ref = "base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
```